# Python not printing beautifulsoup data to .txt file (or I can't find it)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xlrd

I'm trying to put all the anchor text on a page in a txt file

```
print(anchor.get('href'))
with open('file.txt', 'a') as fd:
    fd.write(anchor.get('href') + '\n')
```

and the script executes with no errors but I cannot find file.txt anywhere on my computer. Am I missing out on something really obvious?

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? Do `import os` and `print os.getcwd()` to see where your script will store the file.

Comment: Also, your posted code shows that you are using tabs for indentation. Don't. Use four spaces instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With file open mode `a` (append) the file will be created if it doesn't already exist, otherwise writes will be appended to the end of the file. As written in the question, the file will be created in the current directory of the running process... look there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
with open('file.txt', 'a') as fd:
    links = (link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a'))
    fd.write('\n'.join(links) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a full path to filename, so you can find in this path.

Example:

```
print(anchor.get('href'))
with open('/home/wbk/file.txt', 'a') as fd:
    fd.write(anchor.get('href') + '\n')
```

And yes, you can use 'a' to create a new file, although this is not a good practice. The 'a' is to append data to the end of an existing file as describes [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
with open("example.txt","a") as a:
    a.write("hello")
```

are you sure that the file isn't in your computer? In which ways you have demonstrated it? In my case, i work with eclipse IDE, so I have to refresh the Eclipse file explorer to see it..

Try this:

```
with open("prova.txt","a") as a:
    a.write("ciao")
try: open("prova.txt","r")
except: print "file doesn't exist"
```